# Watch the object and compare in angularjs to trigger css class change if the value is changed

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, compare, watch

Im using AngularJS 1.5x

I have a Web Form to submit Car information  1)model, 2)make to Backend(Api: **SaveCarDetails**).to save this form information in the Backend DB.

On success, I have to make a API call(**GetCarsInfo**) to get the array list of cars information(so far saved in the BE).

I need to display car information Cards showing the make  & model and with EDIT button so that user can update exactly that particular car information and we use (**SaveCarDetails** same API as used for adding new details).

On the succesfull update, I need to again make to call to (**GetBanks**) to get the updated list of bank account information.

Now I need to show Tickmark Icon ONLY on the Car info card that has been updated or newly added.

- What is the best way to do this? (show the icon only on the card that got updated or newly added).
- How to find out exactly which card is updated by comparing or watching an Object? there is no unique identifier that is being passed for any updates to the response object.

I tried to do an $watch on the object but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is the code: http://plnkr.co/edit/RztTjy?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('app', [])
 .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.carobj = [{
         'make': 'acura',   
             'model': "TL",  
             'name':'joe' 
            },  
            {
              'make': "bmw",   
             'model': '5series',  
             'name':'doe'   
            
        }];
        
console.log(vm.carobj);  
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.card{
  border: 10px solid #cccccc;
  width: 200px;
  height:160px;
  margin:20px;
  position:relative;
  
}

.tickWhenUpdated{
  float:right;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  
}

.editbtn{
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="font-awesome@4.3.0" data-semver="4.3.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.5" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angularjs@1.5.7" data-semver="1.5.7" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as mc">
      <div class="card" ng-repeat="car in mc.carobj">
        <p>Car Info Box </p>
        <i class="fa fa-check tickWhenUpdated" aria-hidden="true"></i>


        Account num:{{car.make}}                 <br />


        Routung num: {{car.model}}        <br />
        <input value="edit" class="btn btn-primary editbtn" type="button" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, instead of dynamically updating the class using ng-class or something, you could just set a variable on the car objects called `updated` that is truthy when the car was updated. Then place `ng-show="car.updated"` on the  tag.

Regarding how to set that updated variable on the object, you can either try to manipulate it directly when you click the edit button. Just pass the element to a function which will modify the updated field. Something like;

```
Html:
<div ng-repeat="car in cars">
  <input type="button" ng-click"update(cars, car.id)">
</div>

Js:

$scope.update = function(cars, id) {
  cars = cars.map(function(car) {
    if (car.id == id) {
      car.updated = true
    } else {
      car.updated = false
    }
  })
}
```

If you absolutely don't have an ID, the only thing I can think of is to put something that increments on the object (unix timestamp, incrementor). Something like

```
Js:
$scope.itr = 0;
$scope.update = function(car) {
 $scope.itr++
  car.itr = $scope.itr
}
```

Then have an ngChange on the array that calls a function and sets car.updated to false on all objects except the one with the largest itr value, which it sets to true.

This is a hardcore hack, and I would really try to just have some sort of unique ID.